# Plotly: how to stretch line over the graphics end?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I need to extend line at the end of graphics area, that is made with 2 DataFrame points with DatetimeIndex as on screen below:
[image]

How to do that? With math I would calculate where line exactly hits x axis, buy it's impossible, because you can not measure distance between Jan 4 and Jan 5, because it's 1 day.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'score':[30, 60, 38, 10, 50, 70, 40],
    'date':['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07'],
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_shape(
    dict(
        type="line",
        x0=df.iloc[1]['date'],
        y0=df.iloc[1]['score'],
        x1=df.iloc[2]['date'],
        y1=df.iloc[2]['score'],
        line=dict(
        color="RoyalBlue",
        width=3
    )
))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        mode='markers',
        x=df['date'],
        y=df['score'],
        marker=dict(
            color='LightSkyBlue',
            size=12,
            line=dict(
                color='MediumPurple',
                width=4
            )
        ),
    )
)

fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='auto',)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Do you want it on blue or with red dots?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you convert days in minutes it shouldn't be a big deal. Here I already calculated the date for you

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'score':[30, 60, 38, 10, 50, 70, 40],
    'date':['2000-01-01', '2000-01-02', '2000-01-03', '2000-01-04', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07'],
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_shape(
    dict(
        type="line",
        x0=df.iloc[1]['date'],
        y0=df.iloc[1]['score'],
        x1=df.iloc[2]['date'],
        y1=df.iloc[2]['score'],
        line=dict(
        color="RoyalBlue",
        width=3
    )
))
fig.add_shape(
    dict(
        type="line",
        x0=df.iloc[2]['date'],
        y0=df.iloc[2]['score'],
        x1=pd.Timestamp(2000,1,4,17,16),
        y1=0,
        line=dict(
        color="red",
        dash="dot",
        width=3
    )
))


fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        mode='markers',
        x=df['date'],
        y=df['score'],
        marker=dict(
            color='LightSkyBlue',
            size=12,
            line=dict(
                color='MediumPurple',
                width=4
            )
        ),
    )
)

fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='auto',)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: bro, thank you for reply, but this is extremely inconvenient to translate into minutes. My problem is not just to make graphics with red dots, I have complicate algorithms with machine learning + plotly graphics, this is unreal to convert each time unit every step

Comment: @sirjay I don't understand the downvote. In your question you asked for a line only and you said it was not possible to do it.